# Iterating in intervals of 0.5 for 2 variables simultaneously

Tags: python, for-loop, increment

I am attempting to calculate the mean pitch for each 0.5 frame of a 40.8 second audio file. I have written the following code in Python, however after printing i and j, I don't think this is the correct way to implement this.

```
import itertools

def seq(start, end, step):
    if step == 0:
        raise ValueError("step must not be 0")
    sample_count = int(abs(end - start) / step)
    return itertools.islice(itertools.count(start, step), sample_count)

for i in seq(startTime, endTime, 0.5):
  for j in seq(startTime+0.5, endTime+0.5, 0.5):
     meanPitch = call(pitch, "Get mean", i, j, unit) # get mean pitch
     return(meanPitch)
```

So the code should firstly return the mean pitch for the audio frame between 0 seconds and 0.5 seconds, then the mean pitch between 0.5 and 1.0 seconds, etc. This should continue up until the end time (40.83 seconds). Any advice as to where I am going wrong would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you have `return` right after the calculation in the inner loop. you want to have multiple results as a list, correct? if so, you should create a list and append the result onto it instead of returning the result.

Answer (score 0):

> after printing i and j, I don't think this is the correct way

Splitting 40.8 seconds into 1/2 second intervals gives you roughly 82 intervals. You can iterate over 0-82 along with 1-82 then multiply by .5 to get the beginning and end of each interval.

```
import math
n = 40.8
step = .5
n = math.ceil(n/step)

one = range(n)
two = range(1,n+1)

for i,j in zip(one,two):
    print(i*.5,j*.5)
```

Or just iterate over one and calculate the other.

```
for i in one:
    i *= step
    j = i + step
    print(i,j)
```